# Second MDX Query has to return result for each row returned by 1st MDX Query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a Situation where I am looking for MDX Guidance.

Environment: SQL Server 2008 R2,SSRS 2008 R2

Dimension:Columns
DimMainProvider :ProviderName
DimAcademicYear:AcademicYear
DimSectorSubjectArea:Estyn
DimLearningAim:LearningAimReference

Fact:Columns
Learnings:MainProviderKey,AgeBandKey,LearningAimKey,SuccessFlag

What I want is 
    1) For a particular MainProvider Get Top 10 LearningAims by  Success Rate  and show it in tablix
    2) For a each Row on tablix also show  Box plot graph which essentially needs Min,Max,Quartile1,Quartile3 success rates of that particular LearningAim across all Mainproviders

What I have is 2 MDX queries

> a) one which gets top 10 Activities for a Main Provider (Simplified
>   Version of MDX below)

```
WITH
SET Top10LearningAimsForSuccessRate
AS 
NonEmpty(
        TOPCOUNT([ReportedLearningAims],10,[Measures].[SuccessRate]),
        [Measures].[SuccessRate]
        )
SELECT 
    {
      [Measures].[SuccessRate]
    } ON COLUMNS

 ,NON EMPTY 
    {  
        EXISTS( 
                Top10LearningAimsForSuccessRate
               ,,"Learnings")
     } ON ROWS
FROM 
(

SELECT {[Measures].[TerminatedAssessableLASum]
     ,[Measures].[SuccessfulLASum]} ON COLUMNS
     ,{(StrToSet("[DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].&[44]",CONSTRAINED))} On ROWS
FROM [FECube]
)
WHERE 
  ( StrToSet("[DimAcademicYear].[AcademicYear].[AcademicYear].[2009/10]",CONSTRAINED), 
    StrToSet("[DimSectorSubjectArea].[Estyn].&[2]",CONSTRAINED)
  )
```

> b) Another query which accepts LearningAim as a Parameter and does
>   Statistical Calculations and gives me values (Simplified Version of
>   MDX below)

```
WITH 
SET ProviderwideLearningAims
AS
ORDER(
        NonEmpty( [DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
                  [Measures].[SuccessRate]
                )
        ,[Measures].[SuccessRate],BASC        
    )

MEMBER [Measures].[MaxValue]
AS
Max(ProviderwideLearningAims,[SuccessRate]),FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"

MEMBER [Measures].[MinValue]
AS
Min(ProviderwideLearningAims,[SuccessRate]),FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"

MEMBER [Measures].[MedianValue]
AS
Median(ProviderwideLearningAims,[SuccessRate]),FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"


Member [Measures].[ProviderCount] As [ProviderwideLearningAims].Count   

MEMBER [Measures].[MeanValue]
AS 
(SUM(ProviderwideLearningAims,[SuccessRate])/[Measures].[ProviderCount]),FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"


MEMBER [Measures].[LearningAimUniqueName]
AS
[DimLearningAim].[LearningAimReference].CurrentMember.UniqueName                                  

Select
        {     [Measures].[LearningAimUniqueName]
             ,[Measures].[MinValue]     
             ,[Measures].[MaxValue]
             ,[Measures].[MedianValue]
             ,[Measures].[MeanValue]

        } ON COLUMNS,

       {
        NonEmpty([DimLearningAim].[LearningAimReference].[LearningAimReference],ProviderwideLearningAims)
       } ON ROWS
FROM
(
   SELECT 
   StrToSet("[DimLearningAim].[LearningAimReference].&[50024991]",CONSTRAINED) ON COLUMNS
   FROM [FECube]
   )
WHERE 
  ( StrToSet("[DimAcademicYear].[AcademicYear].[AcademicYear].[2009/10]",CONSTRAINED), 
    StrToSet("[DimSectorSubjectArea].[Estyn].&[2]",CONSTRAINED)

  )
```

> My original Idea is to fire 2nd query for each Learning Aim received
>   from 1st query,but  I am not able to implement this in SSRS  Dataset 
>   Model.
>   So Now I am back at MDX level and want somehow to merge these
>   two.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it with help from Deepak Puri on MSDN forums

> With Set [Top10LearningAims] as TOPCOUNT(
>
> Filter(([ReportedLearningAims]*[DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].MEMBERS),[DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].CURRENTMEMBER
>   IS STRTOMEMBER("[DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].&[44]") )
>            ,10,[Measures].[TerminatedAssessableLASum]
>           )
>
> MEMBER [Measures].[MaxValue] AS
>   Max(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate]),FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent"   MEMBER [Measures].[MinValue] AS
>   Min(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate]),FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent"   MEMBER [Measures].[MedianValue] AS
>   Median(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate]), FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent"
>
> MEMBER [Measures].[MeanValue] AS
>   Avg(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate]), FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent"
>
> Member [Measures].[ProviderCount] as 
>   Count(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate])) Member [Measures].[PercentileInt25] as
>   Int((([Measures].[ProviderCount] - 1) * 25) / 100) Member
>   [Measures].[PercentileFrac25] as (([Measures].[ProviderCount] - 1) *
>   25) / 100
>   - [Measures].[PercentileInt25] Member [Measures].[PercentileLo25] as
>   ([Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   Order(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   BASC).Item([Measures].[PercentileInt25]).Item(0)), FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent" Member [Measures].[PercentileHi25] as
>   ([Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   Order(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   BASC).Item([Measures].[PercentileInt25] + 1).Item(0)), FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent" Member [Measures].[Percentile25Value] as
>   ([Measures].[PercentileLo25] * (1 - [Measures].[PercentileFrac25]))
>   + ([Measures].[PercentileHi25] * [Measures].[PercentileFrac25]),
>   FORMAT_STRING = "Percent" Member [Measures].[PercentileInt75] as
>   Int((([Measures].[ProviderCount] - 1) * 75) / 100) Member
>   [Measures].[PercentileFrac75] as (([Measures].[ProviderCount] - 1) *
>   75) / 100
>   - [Measures].[PercentileInt75] Member [Measures].[PercentileLo75] as
>   ([Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   Order(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   BASC).Item([Measures].[PercentileInt75]).Item(0)), FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent" Member [Measures].[PercentileHi75] as
>   ([Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   Order(NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]), [Measures].[SuccessRate],
>   BASC).Item([Measures].[PercentileInt75] + 1).Item(0)), FORMAT_STRING =
>   "Percent" Member [Measures].[Percentile75Value] as
>   ([Measures].[PercentileLo75] * (1 - [Measures].[PercentileFrac75]))
>   + ([Measures].[PercentileHi75] * [Measures].[PercentileFrac75]),
>   FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"
>
> select {    [Measures].[TerminatedAssessableLASum]
>        ,[Measures].[SuccessfulLASum]
>        ,[Measures].[SuccessRate]
>        ,[Measures].[SectorTerminatedAssessableLASum]
>        ,[Measures].[SectorSuccessfulLASum]
>        ,[Measures].[SectorSuccessRate]
>        ,[Measures].[ProviderCount]   ,[Measures].[MinValue]
>   ,[Measures].[MaxValue]     ,[Measures].[MeanValue]
>   ,[Measures].[Percentile25Value]    ,[Measures].[MedianValue]
>   ,[Measures].[Percentile75Value]} on COLUMNS,
>   EXISTS(NonEmpty(([DimLearningAim].[LearningAimReference].[LearningAimReference],[DimLearningAim].[LearningAimTitle].[LearningAimTitle]),([Top10LearningAims],[Measures].[SuccessRate]))*NonEmpty([DimMainProvider].[ProviderName].[ProviderName],
>   [Measures].[SuccessRate]),,"Learnings") DIMENSION PROPERTIES
>   MEMBER_CAPTION,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS from FECube WHERE
>   ( StrToSet("[DimAcademicYear].[AcademicYear].[AcademicYear].[2009/10]",CONSTRAINED),
>     StrToSet("[DimLearnerAgeBand].[AgeBand].[All]",CONSTRAINED), 
>     StrToSet("[DimLearningCourseLength].[CourseLength].[All]",CONSTRAINED),
>     StrToSet("[DimLearnerEthnicity].[Ethnicity].[All]",CONSTRAINED),
>     StrToSet("[DimLearnerGender].[Gender].[All]",CONSTRAINED),
>     StrToSet("[DimDeprivationDecile].[Decile].[All]",CONSTRAINED),
>     StrToSet("[DimSectorSubjectArea].[Estyn].&[2]",CONSTRAINED),
>     StrToSet("[DimLearningActivityLevel].[ActivityLevel].[All]",CONSTRAINED),
>     StrToSet("[DimLearningActivityType].[ActivityType].[All]",CONSTRAINED)
>   ) CELL PROPERTIES    VALUE  ,BACK_COLOR  ,FORE_COLOR  ,FORMATTED_VALUE
>   ,FORMAT_STRING  ,FONT_NAME  ,FONT_SIZE  ,FONT_FLAGS